# How to remove the border=0 attribute from ASP.NET elements?

Tags: asp.net, border

I am trying to get an aspx page to be ADA compliant and one of the hurdles I have is that ASP.NET list boxes, Check Box Lists(asp:CheckBoxList), and tables renders a border=0 attribute.

Is there a way to get rid of that attribute?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the easiest way is jQuery :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.formTable input[type="checkbox"]').parent().css('border','none');
});
</script>
```

Regarding this as one good person said

> `border="0"` was necessary for `Netscape 4`, which didn't support the usual `CSS` way of doing it properly. Of course not much in `ASP.NET` will actually work with `Netscape 4`, so this attempt at backwards compatibility is pretty pointless.

Incidentally, as well as the ASP.NET controls' markup being poor, it actually still does browser-sniffing in this day and age.